# How to use last variable in swift

Tags: swift

I understand how lazy variable works but I don't know how to implement properly.
Below is just an example:

```
func calculation() -> (firstValue: Float, secondValue: Float) {
    var a: Float = 2
    var b: Float = 2

    for i in 1...1000 {
        a = a + Float(i)
        b = b + Float(i)
        print(i)
    }

    return (a, b)
}
```

---

```
let m = calculation().firstValue
let n = calculation().secondValue
```

when I run it, the **calculation** function ran twice (1000 time + 1000 time), first time to get the value to m, and second time to get the value of n.

What I have to do to force the function **Calculation** to run just only not time and to store the value m and n without repeat the process twice.

Comment: Its hard to tell what you are wanting to do here.  What does a "lazy var" have to do with anything in this question or the code?

Comment: try this ....  let a, b = calculations()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lazy` keyword is used on the class/struct/enum member variables.
For your example, you can implement like this:

```
class Solution {
    lazy var tuple: (firstValue: Float, secondValue: Float) = {
        var a: Float = 2
        var b: Float = 2

        for i in 1...1000 {
            a = a + Float(i)
            b = b + Float(i)
            print(i)
        }

        return (a, b)
    }()
}

let s = Solution()
let m = s.tuple.firstValue
let n = s.tuple.firstValue
```

The `tuple` variable stores the value returned by the following closure which only runs once.

You can also use a variable to record the return value of the function.

```
let pair = calculation()
let m = pair.firstValue
let n = pair.secondValue
```

Answer (score 2):

`lazy` is the keyword to delay the calculation till the result is first used, so it is not for your case.

You can write something like this:

```
let values = calculation()
let m: Float = values.firstValue
let n: Float = values.secondValue
```

Or this:

```
let (m, n) = calculation()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Big thanks for you